# Using LoggerFactory to output to console; Issue with .AddConsole()

Tags: c#, winforms, logging

I am attempting to learn about and implement logging in a c# winforms application. 
In most/all examples and documentation I have found they use `.AddConsole()` which provides me with the following error:

> 'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for AddConsole and no accessible extention method 'Add Console'...

My current code follows:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; //<-----was suggested in an example but does nothing--<<<<
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        public FormMain()
        {
            var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                    .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                    .AddFilter("LoggingConsoleApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
                    .AddConsole() //<-----------------------line with error---------<<<<
                    .AddEventLog();
            });

            ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FormMain>();
            logger.LogInformation("Example log message");

            InitializeComponent();

            ...rest of program follows...
```

Can you assist in pointing out how to get the example code to compile?

If you have a link to where a tutorial/documentation that I can follow, I would greatly appreciate that as well.

I see in the Microsoft Docs that there is an ILoggerFactory.AddProvider(ILoggerProvider) method but I have not had any success with that either.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` nuget package?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 No, I had not. Thank you for clarifying. It works now. I wish the documentation with that example had mentioned that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various different logging mechanisms and you don't get them out of the box. You are missing the appropriate nuget package. You need to add a package reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`. Once you do that, the extension methods should be available to you.

You can find the package on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/3.1.3).